# Ubuntu 17.10 - Installing Maya 2017 Issue ('PNG12_0' not found)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, maya

Ahoy! I recently switched to Linux and I'm trying to install Maya 2017 following this guide: https://linuxhint.com/install-autodesk-maya-2017-ubuntu/

When I run `sudo ./setup`, I get this error:

`./setup: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng12.so.0: version PNG12_0' not found (required by /home/rottenburg/Downloads/maya2017install/libQtGui.so.4)`

I've been trying to fix this for the past 2 hours and I think I'll need some help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

this lib is not is the official repositories. Try this solution https://askubuntu.com/questions/840257/e-package-libpng12-0-has-no-installation-candidate-ubuntu-16-10-gnome#840268 , download the deb package and run a `sudo dpkg -i <pkgName>` to install it.

Comment: I had that problem when my libpng12.so.0 lib was actually a renamed libpng16.so.0  so it was actually PNG16_0